# PHP in Task Scheduler using includes

Tags: php, scheduled-tasks

So I've read many guides on how to run a PHP script from task manager, using the PHP.exe and the -f flag to give it a file.

However none of these seem to allow for me to use the include function (and also reading and editing other files) in my script. The script I'm trying to run includes multiple files from our site that other pages also use as well as this to-be automated script.

Any ideas as to how I can run the PHP file from Task Scheduler (Windows Server 2012 R2 w/ IIS 7.5) whilst having includes in the script?

Comment: Use full paths to the files in your includes

Comment: either use absolute paths for the includes, or make sure that the working directory of the script running under task manager allows it to find/load those included scripts. This isn't anything special about task manager. The same thing holds for ANY execution environment.

Comment: @john-conde  Will document root be fine, or actually written out?

Comment: Written out is safest.

Comment: I am successfully running a PHP script using task manager, and including several files, one of which is in a sub directory to which I'm pointing using a relative path (not absolute) and it works just fine.  The only problem I had was that one of my include files relied on getting a value out of session which obviously does not work in task manager.  Other than that, it just works.